# web3uikit Module not found error even when module is installed

Tags: next.js, material-ui, moralis

When trying to import web3uikit, the next application throws an error Module not found. I tried uninstalling and installing the package again, but it's not working. My package.json also has the dependency, but the error still exists.

I don't know why this is happening, I even tried restarting the development server, but nothing changed. Can anyone please help me understand why this error is happening and how I can resolve it?

```
import {ConnectButton} from 'web3uikit'


import React from 'react'


const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ConnectButton />
            </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was encountering the same error, turns out i have to install this very specific version "^0.1.159"
use :
npm i web3uikit@^0.1.159

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).